# Java loanTable calculator

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a loan calculator. I am having issues with calculating the monthly payments. I am trying to print out the monthly payment for the different interest rates from low to high, incremented by 0.25%.

I suspect there is something wrong with my while loop. Any suggestions?

I always appreciate your help. I am trying to improve my questions.

```
import apcslib.Format;
import chn.util.*;

public class loanTable {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaring Variables
        double k;
        double n;
        double c;
        double p;
        double a;
        double low;
        double high;

        int time;

        //Getting User Input
        ConsoleIO console = new ConsoleIO();

        System.out.println("Amount of the loan: ");
        p = console.readDouble();
        System.out.println("Principal = $" + p);

        System.out.println("The length of loan in years: ");
        time = console.readInt();
        System.out.println("Time = " + time + " years");

        System.out.println("A low interest rate in %: ");
        low = console.readDouble() / 100;
        System.out.println("Low rate = " + low + "%");

        System.out.println("A high interest rate in %: ");
        high = console.readDouble() / 100;
        System.out.println("High rate = " + high + "%");

        //While Loop
        while (low <= high) {

            k = low / 1200.0;
            n = time * 12;
            c = Math.pow((1 + k), n);
            a = (p * k * c) / (c - 1);

            System.out.println("Annual interest rate: " + low * 100);
            System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " + Format.left(a, 2, 2));

            low += (0.25 / 100);
        }
    }

}
```

`

Comment: You state that you're having trouble with the output, but have not told us **what** trouble. Please help us here by being specific and adequately descriptive.

Comment: my outputs are, Annual interest rate: 11.0
Monthly Payment: 282.40
Annual interest rate: 11.25
Monthly Payment: 282.50
Annual interest rate: 11.5
Monthly Payment: 282.61
Annual interest rate: 11.75
Monthly Payment: 282.72

Comment: they are supposed to be, 
     11.00                   952.32
     11.25                   971.26
     11.50                   990.29
     11.75                  1009.41
     12.00                  1028.61

Comment: Could you explain the `Format.left` call? As far as I'm aware `Format` is an abstract class and does not have a `left` method.

Comment: Format.left formats my outputs to 2 decimal places.

Comment: For my outputs my Annual interest rate is correct but the monthly payments are incorrect.

Comment: What are the principal amount, loan term (in years) and interest calculation method (simple interest, monthly reducing, quarterly reducing, etc.)?  How did you find out that the monthly payment should be `952.32` at `11.00%` interest rate?  Are you using the Excel `PMT` function?

Comment: Why is k divided by 1200 ?

Comment: @sprinter look at the top of the source, `Format` is some class imported from somebody else's library, not the standard Java one (apcs = AP Computer Science?)

Comment: @ajb Ah yes I missed that. thanks.

Comment: You're dividing the interest rate by 100 twice.  So instead of computing the payments at an annual rate of 11%, you're actually computing them at a rate of 0.11%.  Although I'm still unsure why that would make such a big difference in the payments.  I'd like to see the values of the inputs, like @manish.

Comment: @ajb, you are right.  The OP is trying to calculate the monthly payments for an initial principal of `100,000` over a term of 30 years using a monthly reducing scheme (I have verified this using the Excel `PMT` function).  In his Java code, the OP is dividing the interest rate by 100 twice (once immediately after reading and then again in the loop).  The fix is to remove one of the divisions by 100.

Comment: I have to input 100000.00 for the amt in loan. 30 for years. 11 for low interest rate and 12 for high.

Comment: @ajb I thought I was dividing 2 interest rates the high and the low?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help I really appreciate it. I am really sorry if I didn't make my question clear and confused everyone. I will try to put more info in my question next time.

Comment: There are actually three places where you divide interest rates by 100; one of them doesn't look like it, because you're also dividing by 12 at the same time to go from an annual to a monthly rate.  So of those three places, one is "high", one is "low", and what is the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the calculation of k. 
It should be

```
 k = low /12;
```

Here is the right version

```
public class loanTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declaring Variables
    double k;
    double n;
    double c;
    double p;
    double a;
    double low;
    double high;

    int time;

    System.out.println("Amount of the loan: ");
    p = 100000; 
    System.out.println("Principal = $" + p);

    System.out.println("The length of loan in years: ");
    time =30 ; 
    System.out.println("Time = " + time + " years");

    System.out.println("A low interest rate in %: ");
    low = 0.11; 
    System.out.println("Low rate = " + low + "%");

    System.out.println("A high interest rate in %: ");
    high = 0.1125; 
    System.out.println("High rate = " + high + "%");

    //While Loop
    while (low <= high) {
        //changed calculation of k
        k = low /12;
        n = time * 12;
        c = Math.pow((1 + k), n);
        a = (p * k * c) / (c - 1);

        System.out.println("Annual interest rate: " + (low * 100));
        System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " +a /* Format.left(a, 2, 2)*/);

        low += (0.25 / 100);
    }
  }
}
```

To answer the second question (" I get the outputs until annual interest rate to 11.75 but I need to to increment to 12.00 how would I do that? "): the while loop stops at 11.75 because of rounding error. See comments and some alternatives to overcome it:

```
public class LoanTable {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaring Variables
        double k;
        double n;
        double c;
        double p;
        double a;
        double low;
        double high;

        int time;

        System.out.println("Amount of the loan: ");
        p = 100000;
        System.out.println("Principal = $" + p);

        System.out.println("The length of loan in years: ");
        time =30 ;
        System.out.println("Time = " + time + " years");

        System.out.println("A low interest rate in %: ");
        low = 0.11;
        System.out.println("Low rate = " + low + "%");

        System.out.println("A high interest rate in %: ");
        high = 0.12;
        System.out.println("High rate = " + high + "%");

        System.out.println("---------------- Not working well  ------------------");
        //While Loop
        while (low <= high) {
            /*
             * changed calculation of k
             */
            k = low /12;
            n = time * 12;
            c = Math.pow((1 + k), n);
            a = (p * k * c) / (c - 1);

            System.out.println("Annual interest rate: " + (low * 100));
            System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " +a /* Format.left(a, 2, 2)*/);

            low += (0.25 / 100);

            /*
             * at the 4th loop low = 0.12000000000000001
             * so low > high and while block is terminated.
             */
             System.out.println("low = "+ low);

         }

        System.out.println("---------------- Alternative 1  ------------------");
        //While Loop
        low = 0.11;
        high = 0.12;
        int counter = 0;
        double interest = low;

        while (  interest <=  high   ) {

            /*
             * changed calculation of k
             */
            k = interest /12;
            n = time * 12;
            c = Math.pow((1 + k), n);
            a = (p * k * c) / (c - 1);

            System.out.println("Annual interest rate: " + (interest * 100));
            System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " +a /* Format.left(a, 2, 2)*/);

            counter++;
            /*
             * recalculate interest from low, to avoid accumulating 
             * rounding error 
             */
            interest = low + ((0.25/100)* counter);
         }

        System.out.println("---------------- Alternative 2  ------------------");
        //While Loop
        low = 0.11;
        high = 0.12;

        /*
         * cast float to reduce the accuracy. A better alternative would be
         * to declare low and high as float
         */
        while (  (float)low <=  (float)high   ) {
            /*
             * changed calculation of k
             */
            k = low /12;
            n = time * 12;
            c = Math.pow((1 + k), n);
            a = (p * k * c) / (c - 1);

            System.out.println("Annual interest rate: " + (low * 100));
            System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " +a /* Format.left(a, 2, 2)*/);

            low += (0.25 / 100);

         }

        System.out.println("---------------- Alternative 3  ------------------");

        //While Loop
        /*
         * work with integer
         */
        int lowInterest  = 1100;
        int highInterest = 1200;

        while (  lowInterest <=  highInterest  ) {
            /*
             * changed calculation of k
             */
            k = (float)lowInterest /(12*10000);
            n = time * 12;
            c = Math.pow((1 + k), n);
            a = (p * k * c) / (c - 1);

            System.out.println("Annual interest rate: " + ((float)lowInterest /100));
            System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " +a /* Format.left(a, 2, 2)*/);

            lowInterest += 25;

         }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Wow thanks that worked. One last question I get the outputs until annual interest rate to 11.75 but I need to to increment to 12.00 how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you are using:

- I: annual interest: 11%
- P: present value of loan $100,000
- N: period: 30 years

The normal formula for calculating the monthly repayment is:

```
(P*I/12)/(1-(1+I/12)^(-n*12))
```

Or, in Java:

```
private double monthlyRepayment(double loanValue, double annualInterest, int termInYears) {
    double monthlyInterest = annualInterest / 12;
    double termInMonths = termInYears * 12;
    return loanValue * monthlyInterest / (1 - Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, -termInMonths));
}
```

This correctly calculates the repayment as $-952.32

Comment: Thanks this formula helped me out a lot!